# how to update an object within an array during an asyncThunk.fulfilled action in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have an AsyncThunk method named `likePost` when a user clicks `like` on a post it will send this action via dispatch. The method runs fine, and in my database the `Post` is updated successfully, but I can't get Redux to update the Post that is liked during the `.fulfilled` method.

Here is what I'm currently working with:

```
// shoes = [{_id: '', title: '', likes: []}, ...{}]
export const likePost = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/likePost',
  async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await userTokenAxios.post(`/${payload}/like`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

[likePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      const post = state.posts.find((post) => post._id === action.payload._id);
      post.likes.push(action.payload.user);
},
```

Comment: shouldn't this be returned ? like return ```return post.likes.push(action.payload.user);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding the post, get the index for that object in state.posts
const post = state.posts.find((post) => post._id === action.payload._id);

```
const postIndex=state.posts.findIndex((post)=> post._id === action.payload._id);
```

Now you can push the `user` in likes array:

```
state.posts[postIndex].likes.push(action.payload.user)
```